# Use of "That" as a conjunction

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

Which one is grammatically correct?

> She is the most talented teacher THAT I've ever known.

or

> She is the most talented teacher I've ever known.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth yes it does, thx

Answer (score 1):

Both of them are perfectly natural and mean the same. 
**'That'** is optional.

*She is the most talented teacher that I have ever known* **or** *She is the most talented teacher I have ever known*.

*The present perfect tense refers to the past and connects your experience or event to the present.*

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct, but the second one is informal; it is recommended to use the first form in writing that is formal enough.